# Web Scraping Identifying executing and troubleshooting a request

Tags: python, debugging, web-scraping, python-requests, web-inspector

I am having some trouble scraping data from the following website:

> https://www.loft.com.br/apartamentos/sao-paulo-sp?q=pin

When we load the page, it loads the first ~30 posts on real state in the city of Sao Paulo.
If we scroll down, it loads more posts.

Usually I would use selenium to get around this - but I want to learn how to do it properly - I imagine that is by fiddling with requests.

By using inspect on chrome, and watching for what happens when we scroll down, I can see a request made which I presume is what retrieves the new posts.

[image]

If I copy its content as curl, I get the following command:

```
curl "https://landscape-api.loft.com.br/listing/search?city=S^%^C3^%^A3o^%^20Paulo^&facetFilters^\[^\]=address.city^%^3AS^%^C3^%^A3o^%^20Paulo^&limit=18^&limitedColumns=true^&loftUserId=417b37df-19ab-4014-a800-688c5acc039d^&offset=28^&orderBy^\[^\]=rankB^&orderByStatus=^%^27FOR_SALE^%^27^%^2C^%^20^%^27JUST_LISTED^%^27^%^2C^%^20^%^27DEMOLITION^%^27^%^2C^%^20^%^27COMING_SOON^%^27^%^20^%^2C^%^20^%^27SOLD^%^27^&originType=LISTINGS_LOAD_MORE^&q=pin^&status^\[^\]=FOR_SALE^&status^\[^\]=JUST_LISTED^&status^\[^\]=DEMOLITION^&status^\[^\]=COMING_SOON^&status^\[^\]=SOLD" ^
  -X "OPTIONS" ^
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" ^
  -H "Accept: */*" ^
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" ^
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: loft_user_id,loftuserid,utm_campaign,utm_content,utm_created_at,utm_id,utm_medium,utm_source,utm_term,utm_user_agent,x-user-agent,x-utm-source,x-utm-user-id" ^
  -H "Origin: https://www.loft.com.br" ^
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty" ^
  -H "Referer: https://www.loft.com.br/" ^
  -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9" ^
  --compressed
```

I am unsure which would be the proper way to convert this to a command to be used in python module **requests** - so I used this website - https://curl.trillworks.com/ - to do it.

The result is:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'loft_user_id,loftuserid,utm_campaign,utm_content,utm_created_at,utm_id,utm_medium,utm_source,utm_term,utm_user_agent,x-user-agent,x-utm-source,x-utm-user-id',
    'Origin': 'https://www.loft.com.br',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://www.loft.com.br/',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

params = (
    ('city', 'S\xE3o Paulo'),
    ('facetFilters/[/]', 'address.city:S\xE3o Paulo'),
    ('limit', '18'),
    ('limitedColumns', 'true'),
    ('loftUserId', '417b37df-19ab-4014-a800-688c5acc039d'),
    ('offset', '28'),
    ('orderBy/[/]', 'rankB'),
    ('orderByStatus', '\'FOR_SALE\', \'JUST_LISTED\', \'DEMOLITION\', \'COMING_SOON\' , \'SOLD\''),
    ('originType', 'LISTINGS_LOAD_MORE'),
    ('q', 'pin'),
    ('status/[/]', ['FOR_SALE', 'JUST_LISTED', 'DEMOLITION', 'COMING_SOON', 'SOLD']),
)

response = requests.options('https://landscape-api.loft.com.br/listing/search', headers=headers, params=params)
```

However, when I try to run it, I get a **204**.

So my questions are:

1. What is the proper/best way to identify requests from this website? Are there any better alternatives to what I did?
2. Once identified, is copy as curl the best way to replicate the command?
3. How to best replicate the command in Python?
4. Why am I getting a 204?

Comment: Ruvee is correct. You need to update from `requests.options` to `requests.get`. Then you can use `response.json()` to retrieve the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way to find requests is correct. But you need to find and analyze correct requests.
About why you get 204 response code with no results; you send `OPTION` requests instead of `GET`. In Chrome DevTools you can see two similar requests (check attached picture). One is `OPTION` and second one is `GET` with type [xhr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).
For the website you need the second one, but you used `OPTION` in your code `requests.options(..)`
[image]
To see response of the request select it and check response or preview tab. [image]

One of the best HTTP libraries in Python is [requests](/questions/tagged/requests).

And here's complete code to get all search results:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'x-user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                    'Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36',
    'utm_created_at': '',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers

    listings = list()
    limit = 18
    offset = 0
    while True:
        params = {
            "city": "São Paulo",
            "facetFilters/[/]": "address.city:São Paulo",
            "limit": limit,
            "limitedColumns": "true",
            # "loftUserId": "a2531ad4-cc3f-49b0-8828-e78fb489def8",
            "offset": offset,
            "orderBy/[/]": "rankA",
            "orderByStatus": "\'FOR_SALE\', \'JUST_LISTED\', \'DEMOLITION\', \'COMING_SOON\' , \'SOLD\'",
            "originType": "LISTINGS_LOAD_MORE",
            "q": "pin",
            "status/[/]": ["FOR_SALE", "JUST_LISTED", "DEMOLITION", "COMING_SOON", "SOLD"]
        }
        r = s.get('https://landscape-api.loft.com.br/listing/search', params=params)
        r.raise_for_status()

        data = r.json()
        listings.extend(data["listings"])

        offset += limit
        total = data["pagination"]["total"]
        if len(data["listings"]) == 0 or len(listings) == total:
            break

print(len(listings))
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1- You did it the proper way! I have been doing it the same way for a long time, and based on my experiences on webscraping, using `your browser network tab` is by far the best way to get info about the requests made on a website, better than any "extension" and/or "plugin" that I know of!!! There is also "burp suit" on `kali linux` or `on windows`, but again the network tab on the browser is always my number one choice!

> 2- I have been using the same website that you mentioned!!! It makes my life easier and works seamlessly fine. Of curse, you could do it manually, but the website you mentioned makes it easier and faster for me, and I have been using it for a long time!

> 3- You could do it manually, it's pretty straightforward, but like I said, the website you mentioned makes it easier and faster .

> 4- It's probably because you're using `requests.options`, I would try to use `requests.get` instead!!!